# WebSocket connection to OpenShift app failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, openshift

I created an app with NodeJS and I'm using ws module. If I test the app in localhost it works and there isn't any problem to connect websockets. Now I've upload the app to Openshift and when I try to access from the client it returns that is not possible to stablish a connection to the websocket.

If I do a tail in putty to my app I have this message: **DEBUG: This type of response MUST NOT have a body. Ignoring data passed to end().**

The code that I have in the server is:

```
#!/bin/env node

//Openshift variables
var ipaddress = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || "192.168.69.42";
var port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;


//NodeJS require modules
var Enum = require('enum');
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
    wss = new WebSocketServer({host:ipaddress, port:port});
var fs = require('fs');


wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Connection from origin: ' + ws._socket.remoteAddress);
});

console.log((new Date()) + " Server is listening on: " + ipaddress + ':' port);
```

And in the client:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.69.42:8080/");

ws.onopen = function() {
    console.log("Connected.");
    ws.send("This is the client speaking.");
};
```

Comment: You're using your local address on a client side `ws://192.168.69.42:8080/`, change it to domain you got from OpenShift  (with new domain it'll looks somethong like `ws://yourapp-yourname.rhcloud.com/`) and add port your reach from OPENSHIFT (simply log it and use in client after)

Comment: I put the code with the localhost url. I tried with the correct url to my app and it's when I have the errors.

Comment: Please, check your code first. Missing comma after `WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server`, plus in concat line `console.log((new Date()) + " Server is listening on: " + ipaddress + ':' port);`, `//` before domain on client code. It's pretty hard to reproduce your bug to help.

Comment: Sorry for the errors, I fixed them and continue happening

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For all WebSocket connections on OpenShift you need to use port `8000`  (for Secured sessions it would be `8443`). So, your server example works well (I run them after removing the unnecessary line `var Enum = require('enum');`, you just need to hardcode the port on client to `8000`:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://YourApp-YourName.rhcloud.com:8000"); 

ws.onopen = function(){
  console.log('opened')
}
```

More information [here](https://blog.openshift.com/paas-websockets/).

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example on github that works that you can check out: https://github.com/developercorey/openshift-nodejs-http-and-websocket-example

Comment: This one looks useful too, though I've not tried it yet: https://blog.openshift.com/get-chatty-with-nodejs-and-html5/

Comment: Both links are `404`.