# Connecting to Openshift Python socket server via Adobe Air client

Tags: python, sockets, air, openshift, xmlsocket

Currently i have work on Python socket server on Openshift. Managed to get it listen to port (15000) and tested on local with telnet seems working fine.

However, i unable to connect to the socket server other than local ( either telnet to the socket server or using Adobe Air xmlsocket )
when i do a netstat on the server, i got following result:

```
   netstat -tan | grep $OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_IP | grep $OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_PORT | grep ESTABLISHED
   /proc/net/tcp: Permission denied
```

not sure whether i missed anything on the configuration on Openshift.

Btw, how can i get the IP of my server? if i use OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_IP the ip is only for local right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WebSocket connection to OpenShift app failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19948974/websocket-connection-to-openshift-app-failed)

Answer (score 0):

Your websocket server needs to listen on port 8080, and you need to access it at ws://app-domain.rhcloud.com:8000