# How to handle HTTP upgrade in ExpressJS?

Tags: node.js, express

The newest ExpressJS doesn't inherit from http.Server anymore.

If I try to listen on the `upgrade` event, the server will answer with a `404 Not Found`.

Current [simplified] code is:

```
app.on('upgrade', function(req, socket, head) { /* ... */ });
```

If I try to search for the answer on Google, I'll only find links related to "3.0 -> 4.0 express *upgrade*", not **HTTP** *upgrade*.

### EDIT:

As requested by @jfriend00 , my express initialization [simplified] code:

```
app = express.createServer();
app.listen(self.port, self.ipaddress);
```

Comment: I don't think Express ever inherited from the http server.  It provides request listeners for your server.  If you call `.listen()` on the Express `app` object, it will create an http.Server for you like this: `var server = http.createServer(this);`.  So, it appears that your hypothesis about it not using http.Server is wrong.  You should be able to use [this technique](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_upgrade) on the http server object to listen for the upgrade event.

Comment: Please show your express initialization code so we can direct you how to use the http server object to do this rather than the Express object.

Comment: `express.createServer()` has been deprecated for a long time and removed from Express 4.  You would create the `app` object in Express 4 with `var app = express()`.  The http server object is then returned from `var server = app.listen(...)` if you need direct access to the http server object.  What version of Express are you using?

Comment: I upgraded to ExpressJS 4.11.2 a few seconds ago. After making the change you mentioned, it still didn't work. `upgrade`ing on the object returned by `app.listen` doesn't seem to work. And I still see headers like `X-Powered-By:"Express"` injected by ExpressJS.

Comment: Sorry, but it's hard to comment on code we can't see.  If you're using Express, I don't know why you're surprised to see Express headers.

Comment: Sorry, there is no reason for me to hide the code. It's for an open source project, after all. The whole ExpressJS using code is under 187 lines: https://gist.github.com/vinipsmaker/90268edc43e4e240cdde Just looking for app may do the trick. I'm surprised to see the ExpressJS header in the **upgrade** event. **I** wanna handle these.

Comment: @jfriend00 , sorry, your suggestion fixed the code, actually. But there was [another problem in the **deployment** of OpenShift](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19952072/883113)

Comment: OK, good to know.  I put my recommendation into an answer so you can wrap up this question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since my comment seemed to work for you, I'll put it in an answer.

`express.createServer()` has been deprecated for a long time and removed from Express 4. You would create the app object in Express 4 with:

```
var app = express()
```

The http server object is then returned from

```
var server = app.listen(...)
```

If you need direct access to the http server object.

Answer (score 11):

Create a HTTP server with an express app:

```
const app = express()

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.on('upgrade', function (req, socket, head) {
  // ...
});

server.listen(5000);
```

see https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2556#issuecomment-75310480

Comment: what does the "upgrade" event mean? is it different from "connect"?

Comment: @AlexanderMills https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Protocol_upgrade_mechanism